# Substitution Cipher, Strings and Functions

Tags: c++, string, function, encryption

Where I am stuck at is the EncryptString function. The EncryptFile function will take a .txt file and convert the .txt to a C string equivalent, then pass that into the EncrpytString function. When I pass it in, the Substitution function will do its work with the cipher string and encrypt the individual characters, then spit that back out into a new string called encrypted_string. However, I cannot get this function to accept the argument passed into it. Any guidance?

This is where the program currently is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

char substitution_cipher(string cipher_key, char char_to_encrypt);
char reverse_substitution_cipher(string cipher_key, char char_to_encrypt);

string EncryptString(string &cipher_key, string string_to_be_encrypted);
string DecryptString(string &cipher_key, string string_to_be_decrypted);

void RotateCipherKey(string &cipher_key);
void DisplayFile(string filename);


void EncryptFile(string cipher_key, string filename_from, string filename_to);
void DecryptFile(string cipher_key, string filename_from, string filename_to);

int main()
{
    string cipher_key = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

    EncryptFile(cipher_key, "test.txt", "test-encrypted.txt");
    DecryptFile(cipher_key, "test-encrypted.txt", "test-ed.txt");

    DisplayFile("test.txt");
    DisplayFile("test-encrypted.txt");
    DisplayFile("test-ed.txt");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


//  Rotate the cipher key. Example: abcdef becames bcdefa

void RotateCipherKey(string &cipher_key)
{
    rotate(cipher_key.begin(), cipher_key.begin() + 1, cipher_key.end());
}

// Perform a substitution cipher on a single character 
// using the specified cipher key
char SubstitutionCipher(string cipher_key, char char_to_encrypt)
{
    for (int iii = 0; iii < cipher_key.length(); iii++)
    {
        RotateCipherKey(cipher_key);
        char_to_encrypt = cipher_key[iii];
    }
    return char_to_encrypt;
}

// Perform a "reverse" substitution cipher on a single character 
// using the specified cipher key
char ReverseSubstitutionCipher(string cipher_key, char char_to_decrypt)
{
    for (int iii = 0; iii < cipher_key.length(); iii++)
    {
        RotateCipherKey(cipher_key);
        char_to_decrypt = cipher_key[iii];
    }
    return char_to_decrypt;
}

// Encrypt String and return it 
// You will use the SubstitutionCipher() function to encrypt the
// individual characters
// 
// Note: We will call RotateCipherKey() after each time we encrypt 
// a character.
string EncryptString(string &cipher_key, string string_to_be_encrypted)
{
    char *y = string_to_be_encrypted.c_str();
    {
        //SubstitutionCipher(cipher_key, string_to_be_encrypted);
    }
    cout << " " << string_to_be_encrypted;
    string encrypted_string = string_to_be_encrypted;
    return encrypted_string;
}

// Decrypt String and return it 
// You will use the ReverseSubstitutionCipher() function to decrypt the
// individual characters
//
// Note: We will call RotateCipherKey() after each time we encrypt 
// a character.
string DecryptString(string &cipher_key, string string_to_be_decrypted)
{
    string decrypted_string = string_to_be_decrypted;

    return decrypted_string;
}

// Display file specified by the filname parameter

void DisplayFile(string filename)
{
    string str;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename);
    infile >> str;
    while (infile)
    {
        cout << " " << str;
        infile >> str;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


// Encrypt the specified file using the specified cipher key and 
// write the output to a different file
// This function is complete
void EncryptFile(string cipher_key, string filename_from, string filename_to)
{
    string input;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    infile.open(filename_from.c_str());
    outfile.open(filename_to.c_str());

    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Can not open input file " + filename_from << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    if (!outfile)
    {
        cout << "Can not open Output file " + filename_to << endl;
        exit(0);
    }


    while (getline(infile, input))
    {
        outfile << EncryptString(cipher_key, input) << endl;
    }
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
}

// Decrypt the specified file using the specified cipher key and 
// write the output to a different file
// This function is complete
void DecryptFile(string cipher_key, string filename_from, string filename_to)
{
    string input;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    infile.open(filename_from.c_str());
    outfile.open(filename_to.c_str());

    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Can not open input file " + filename_from << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    if (!outfile)
    {
        cout << "Can not open Output file " + filename_to << endl;
        exit(0);
    }


    while (getline(infile, input))
    {
        outfile << DecryptString(cipher_key, input) << endl;
    }
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
}
```

### EDIT//

```
string EncryptString(string &cipher_key, string string_to_be_encrypted)
{
    char new_char;
    for (int iii = 0; iii < string_to_be_encrypted.length(); iii++)
    {
        new_char = SubstitutionCipher(cipher_key, string_to_be_encrypted[iii]);
        RotateCipherKey(cipher_key);
    }
    string encrypted_string = string_to_be_encrypted;
    cout << " " << encrypted_string;
    return encrypted_string;
}
```

Ok here is new code now with some modifications.

Comment: how do you invoke the function? what is the error that you get?

Comment: The function SubstitutionCipher is called in EncryptString which is called by EncryptFile. The error is in line char *y=string_to_be_encrypted.c_str(); which the error i get is that a const char cannot initialize a type char*. I believe what i need to do is convert the string passed into EncryptString into an array of chars, but im not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that `c_str()` returns a pointer to const, `const char*`, which you can not assign to a `char*` in the line

```
char* y=string_to_be_encrypted.c_str(); // cannot assign a `const char*` to `char*`
```

Use directly the string to perform your work. There is no other way of getting a   pointer to non-const `char` to the data of a `std::string`.

Comment: Ok. So if i pass the string to SubstitutionCipher, such as SubstitutionCipher(cipher_key, encrypted_string); I will receive an error that i cannot convert from string to char. How can I pass that string to the function?

Comment: @jokersaidit pass the `char` directly, such as `string_to_be_encripted[10]` for the 10-th `char` in `string_to_be_encripted`

Comment: Ok made edit in original post. Now i understand the logic behind passing the char to the function. I do have a follow up question for you. Now that I have the index of the string being passed into the SubstitutionCipher function, it will run through the loop and return a new letter each time. How can i take all these new letters and stuff them into a new string?

Comment: start with an empty string then use push_back, or preallocate memory for the string and use tipical [ ] access to add elements

Comment: Adding elements is working. Almost there. Now need to fix spacing and punctuation to actually have it look encrypted. Here is example:  
This is some Random gibberish.

Please check all lines for proper encrypt and decrypt.

Hopefully, you got this working.

zoac fn qbvh tgezyt qrbnejozp.

zjaiqf fzkjm krt utaek ujx xbcbfw jqjugus xom wrelqlb.

fcbfhybnd, huf waj lipx qzbkjvj.

Comment: @jokersaidit you have to think what to do with the non-alphanumerical characters. Why don't you add them to your substitution table? If you choose to ignore them, then the best thing to do is to strip the string from any punctuation/spaces (use `std::isalnum` to test whether a `char` is alphanumeric or not.)